# What's the name of the song at the end of No. 6 episode 4?

Tags: music, no.-6

Does anyone know the name of the song that starts playing as Sion's mom reads the note from Sion at the end of episode 4, "Good and Evil"?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the song is Rokutousei No Yoru by artist Aimer. You can hear a full version of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsxUEp2dTPA).